# Как в Adapter для RecyclerView передать два документа из разных коллекций Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, recyclerview.adapter, firestore

Есть две коллекции `Lesson` и `Lecturer`, `RecyclerView` выводит документы класса `Lesson` из коллекции `Lesson` и информацию о преподавателя из документа класса `Lecturer` путь к которому в `Firestore` записан в поле объекта `lesson` (`lecturer_path: "Lecturer / -название файла-"`). Сейчас я получу данные преподавателя в `LessonAdapter`:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                DocumentReference docRefLecturer = db.document(lesson.getLecturer_path());

docRefLecturer.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    Lecturer lecturer = documentSnapshot.toObject(Lecturer.class);

                    lecturerView.setText(lecturer.getName() + "  " + lecturer.getMiddlename());
                }
            });
```

Но это занимает больше времени и создает ошибки. Если создать `Query` со всеми преподавателями в `MainActyvity` так же как `Lesson`, как передать ее в `LessonAdapter`?

```
//MainActyvity
private void initFirestore() {
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        // Get the 50 lessons
        mLessonQuery = mFirestore
                .collection(LESSON_COLLECTION_PATH)
                .orderBy("number", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .limit(LIMIT);

        mLecturerQuery = mFirestore
                .collection(lECTURER_COLLECTION_PATH)
                .orderBy("surname", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    }
    .....

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        if (mLessonQuery == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "No query, not initializing RecyclerView");
        }

        mAdapter = new LessonAdapter(mLessonQuery, this) {

            @Override
            protected void onDataChanged() {
                // Show/hide content if the query returns empty.
                if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                    mLessonsRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mLessonsRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                // Show a snackbar on errors
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        mLessonsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mLessonsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    //LessonAdapter
    public class LessonAdapter extends FirestoreAdapter<LessonAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface OnLessonSelectedListener {

        void onLessonSelected(DocumentSnapshot lesson);

    }

    private OnLessonSelectedListener mListener;

    public LessonAdapter(Query query, OnLessonSelectedListener listener) {
        super(query);
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lesson, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListener);
    }
```

Comment: Firebase - это NoSQL решение, смотрите в сторону https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: да и вообще, при активном чтении/записи документов коллекции, наступит суточная квота от Firebase, если вы конечно не на платном тарифе обслуживаетесь))